# Capistrano - Rails Error: Unable to access log file + unicorn: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I am trying to deploy code with using Capistrano and facing these error:

```
 ** [out :: IP] Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/deployer/apps/projectname_production/releases/20150224143955/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

I've tried to create the file `production.log` in the `/log` directory (and `chmod 0666 production.log`) and deployed it to the server, but the error is still there.
What am I missing there?

I faced one more error while deployment:

```
 ** [out :: IP] bash: /etc/init.d/unicorn_projectname: Permission denied
```

I checked this file on the server and there's following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   68 Feb 24 14:20 unicorn_projectname -> /home/deployer/apps/projectname_production/current/config/unicorn_init.sh
```

What permissions should have this file?

Thank you in advance for help.

**EDIT:** if I log in to the server and run this command - `touch production.log` on the server, I get `touch: cannot touch 'production.log': Permission denied`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo touch /home/deployer/apps/projectname_production/releases/20150224143955/log/production.log

sudo chmod 0666 /home/deployer/apps/projectname_production/releases/20150224143955/log/production.log
```